# Como separa las planillas de excel que dan error, de las que no?

Tags: python-3.x

Tengo un directorio de aprox 3000 plantillas de excel que necesito consolidar y no estan en un formato que pueda llegar y consolidar, por lo que tengo que procesarlas para poder consolidarlas, lamentablemente no todas son iguales, por lo que quiero separa las que son diferentes para poder analizarlas con mas detalle.

```python
#defino funcion de trasnformacion de plantillas
    def funcion_rich(ruta_root):
        os.chdir(ruta_root)
        df0 = []
        ls_file_pdf=[]
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(".", topdown = False):
            for name in files:
                x=os.path.join(root, name)
                ls_file_pdf.append(x)
        ls_file_xlsx=[x for x in ls_file_pdf if ".xlsx" in x]

    #loop para recorrer todos los archivos terminados en ".xlsx"
            for file in ls_file_xlsx:
                try:
                    if file.endswith('.xlsx'):
                        book = openpyxl.load_workbook(file)
                        hoja= book.active
        
                        celdas = hoja["B12":"C19"]
                        celdas1= hoja["G12":"H15"]
                        celdas2= hoja["B23":"M100"]
        
                        rows_list = []
                        rows_list2= []
        
                # Loop through each row and get the values in the cells
                        for row in celdas:
                    # Get a list of all columns in each row
                            cols = []
                            for col in row:
                                cols.append(col.value)
                            rows_list.append(cols)
        
                # Create a pandas dataframe from the rows_list.
                # The first row is the column names
                 
        
                        for row in celdas1:
                    # Get a list of all columns in each row
                            cols = []
                            for col in row:
                                cols.append(col.value)
                            rows_list.append(cols)
        
                # Create a pandas dataframe from the rows_list.
                # The first row is the column names
                        df = pd.DataFrame(data=rows_list[1:], index=None, columns=rows_list[0])
        
                        for row in celdas2:
                    # Get a list of all columns in each row
                            cols = []
                            for col in row:
                                cols.append(col.value)
                            rows_list2.append(cols)
        
                # Create a pandas dataframe from the rows_list.
                        df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=rows_list2[1:], index=None, columns=rows_list2[0])
                        if "Sexo" in df2.columns:
                            df2.drop(columns=["Sexo"],inplace=True)
                        else:
                            df2=df2.iloc[:,:-1]
                        df2.dropna(how="all",inplace=True)
        
                #Transpongo las celdas y las concateno para dejarlas en un formato analizable
        
                        df1=df.transpose()
                        df1.columns=df1.iloc[0]
                        df1.reset_index(inplace=True)
                        df1.drop(0,inplace=True)
                        df1.rename(columns={"index":"Nombre Empresa"},inplace=True)
                        df1.reset_index(inplace=True,drop=True)
                        df1.set_index('Nombre Empresa')
                        rut_empresa=df1["Rut Empresa"].values[0]
                        df2["Rut Empresa"] = rut_empresa   
                        df3 = pd.merge(df1,df2, on = "Rut Empresa")
               
                        if df3.shape[0] != 0:
                            df0.append(df3) 
                 
                        x=np.array(df3.columns)
                        print(x)
                        print(file)
                        x=np.unique(x)
                        if len(x)!=len(df3.columns):
                            print(f"Valores repetidos en nombres de columnas en {file}")
                    df0=pd.concat(df0)
                    df0.to_excel("C:/Users/Ricardo/Documents/Consolidado/Macarena.xlsx", index=False)
                except:
                    src=r"C:/Users/Ricardo/Documents/Consolidado/MACARENA/"+file.replace("\\","/").replace("./","")
                    des=r"C:/Users/Ricardo/Documents/Consolidado/Malos/" + file.replace("\\","/").replace("./","")
                    os.rename(src,des)
```

Mi intencion con el "Try" era que intentara hacer el proceso de consolidado y si ocurre algun error el archivo se moviera a otro directorio, pero termina cambiando de lugar todas las planilas.

Comment: que son planillas??? yo conozco es de plantillas ... planilla para mi es la lista de pagos a empleados a fin de quincena o semana ...

Comment: son archivos excel.

Comment: eso no fue lo que yo pregunte...

Comment: que son planillas??? son archivos excel. 
En Chile se le dice asi. 
No se como mas ayudarte amigo...

Comment: lo que pasa es que aquí no todos son chilenos ... y no conocemos los términos de tu pais ... técnicamente eso que llamas planilla debe tener un nombre ...

Comment: Ya te ha dicho que son archivos excel, no sé qué más pretendes obtener. ¿Deseas ayudar? A poco que mires el código que ha insertado verás que en una línea pone '#loop para recorrer todos los archivos terminados en ".xlsx"'.

Comment: Trata de capturar el error que te da, pon `except Exception as e: print(e)` y mira que error da. Luego de eso edita tu pregunta añadiendo esos detalles